# Hide Tool Tip on SharePoint 2010 Calendar Event for Month View

Tags: calendar, css

I need to hide the tool tip for a SharePoint 2010 calendar event in the month view.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with the following CSS code.  Edit the page, add a CEWP and put this in the source.

```
.ms-acal-time{display:none;}
```

Comment: that only seems to hide the time not the hover window... hm...